# Sqlalchemy and DBvisualizer failing with port fowarding

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, port, dbvisualizer

To connect to our database, we need to use port forward to connect to the remote instance.

```
ssh -i [ssh Key] -f -N -L [local port]:[host]:[remote port] [user]@[remote ip]
```

Afterwards, I can then use this command to access the remote database.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P [local port] -u [database user] -p
```

If I use the local settings in something like SQLAlchemy or DbVisualizer however, I get

> Access denied for user [user]@'10.0.1.70' (using password:
>   YES)

I know the password is correct, so what am I missing in my understanding? What is the difference here between the cli and these other interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

For DbVisualizer, have you tried specifying Database Server as "localhost", as described here:

http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Using+an+SSH+Tunnel

Best Regards
Hans Bergsten (DbVisualizer developer)